# How to select value from search dropdown In selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to import all the values from a dropdown menu to combobox in my GUI .

After that I need to select a value by click on combobox.

but it did not work.
Please help me with selecting a value from the dropdown. 
How do i get all text values available in the dropdown ?

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
import time
import os

    def first(self):

        url = 'https://www....aspx'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
        driver.get(url)
        s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('select2-ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_ddlClass-container'))

        all_options = s1.options
        for options in all_options:
            self.comboBoxClass.addItem(options.text)
            print(options.text)

        self.comboBoxClass.activated.connect(self.loading_2)

    def loading_2(self):
        s1.select_by_visible_text(str(self.comboBoxClass.currentText()))
```

HTML code:

```html
<div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_oClassUpdatePanel">

        <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_trEmptyRow" class="col-xs-12 no_padding">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4">
                <span class="manditory"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8 feild_data">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_trClass" class="col-xs-12 no_padding">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 feild_title divDistributionSearchTitle">
                <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_tdStar04" class="manditory">*</span>
                <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_lblClass" class="StandardFont" style="display:inline-block;width:120px;">class</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8 feild_data divDistributionSearchData">
                <select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$oDistributionUC$ddlClass" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$oDistributionUC$ddlClass\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_ddlClass" class="control-dropdownlist" style="width:100%;">
            <option selected="selected" value="-99">-- chose --</option>
            <option value="1,1">good1 </option>
            <option value="2,1">good2 </option>
            <option value="3,1">good3 </option>
            <option value="4,1">good4 </option>
            <option value="5,1">good5 </option>
            <option value="6,1">good6 </option>

        </select>



                <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_tdValidatorClass">
                    <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_oUpdatePanelrfvClass">

                            <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_rfvClass" class="ValidationClass" style="display:inline-block;width:100px;display:none;"> chose class.</span>
```

value like good1,good2,good3,...

update:

Thanks NitishKshirsagar
this is working now:

```py
drop_down = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_trClass .divDistributionSearchData')

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(drop_down).perform()
drop_down.click()
drop_down = driver.switch_to.active_element

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_trClass .divDistributionSearchData select")
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in all_options:
    print(option.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the dropdown is not of the Select type, you cannot use the Select method on this dropdown. You need to click on the element using its xpath.
You can do it like:

```
em = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='select2-selection select2-selection--single']//span[@id='select2-ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_oDistributionUC_ddlClass-container']")
```

Comment: But when I try to select the value in the dropdown
{
```python

em.send_keys(‘good’)

```
}
I get an error:


[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="86d38f2bb3a8742f162b87f0743ecf90", element="018c2e5b-30a1-4813-b81f-2355122aecff")>]

<class 'list'>

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409

Comment: now i can see the Select tag for your dropdowns. Try to locate your nearest div with id and traverse through it to your select tag. and then work on that select webelement.

Comment: @Awad Please do accept the answer. If you are happy with the solution.